# Java Servlet - response.sendRedirect() returning file source

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a log in page and if the user goes to login.jsp, I call

```
$http.post("AutoLogin?uuid=" + uuid).then(
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

Then in my servlet I have:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

//Check user is logged in
//if user is logged in
response.sendRedirect("portal.jsp#/dashboard.jsp");
return;
}
```

But the redirect does not happen and in the response I see it console.log the html of dashboard.jsp. Why wont it redirect?

Thanks

Comment: Because it's a response to an AJAX request, and your JS code is thus supposed to handle the response, not the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The request you are sending through AJAX. Here what happens the request and response calls works fine, but the response you are getting that is limited to that AJAX call, hence you will get that particular response through the AJAX response only.
Please make the call either by not using AJAX or after getting the response make it redirect from function(response) method in jquery/javascript.

Comment: If I was going to not call it using ajax what would I use to have the browser handle the response

Comment: If you are not using ajax call, then you can go for <form method="post"> and if you are calling through ajax, after getting the response by ajax call, you can write window.location = "portal.jsp#/dashboard.jsp"; in ajax success method.